# Method PUT OneToMany relation? (api-platform)

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Actualite Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"get"}, "enable_max_depth"=true},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"write"}}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ActualiteRepository")
 */
class Actualite
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string titre actualite
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Groups({"get", "write"})
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @var text contenu actualite
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Groups({"write", "get"})
     */
    private $contenu;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="actualite", cascade={"all"})
     * @Groups({"get"})
     */
    private $comments;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function getTitre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    public function setTitre(string $titre): self
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Comment[]
     */
    public function getComments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function addComment(Comment $comment): self
    {
        if (!$this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments[] = $comment;
            $comment->setActualite($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeComment(Comment $comment): self
    {
        if ($this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments->removeElement($comment);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($comment->getActualite() === $this) {
                $comment->setActualite(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContenu(): ?string
    {
        return $this->contenu;
    }

    public function setContenu(string $contenu): self
    {
        $this->contenu = $contenu;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

Comment Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"get"}, "enable_max_depth"=true},
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommentRepository")
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Actualite", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="actualite_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Groups({"get"})
     * @MaxDepth(1)
     */
    private $actualite;

    /**
     * @var string email
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $email;


    /**
     * @var text commentaire
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Groups({"get"})
     */
    private $message;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ajouter = new \Datetime();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getActualite(): ?Actualite
    {
        return $this->actualite;
    }

    public function setActualite(?Actualite $actualite): self
    {
        $this->actualite = $actualite;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMessage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    public function setMessage(string $message): self
    {
        $this->message = $message;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

after i insert some data in tables all work perfect :

in table Actualite

```
+----+---------+---------+ 
| id | titre   | contenu |
+----+---------+---------+ 
| 1  | titre1  | lorem 1 |
| 2  | titre2  | lorem2  |
| 3  | titre3  | lorem3 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

in table Comment

```
+----+--------------+---------+-----------+
| id | actualite_id | email   | message   |
+----+--------------+---------+-----------+ 
| 1  |       1      | e@e.com | someText  |
| 2  |       2      | b@b.com | someText1 |
| 3  |       2      | a@a.com | text      |
| 4  |       3      | q@a.com | text2     |
+----+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

I want to change the ID of a iten (id=2) in the Actualite table, i must also change the actualite_id in the related table : like this ==>

in table Actualite

```
+----+---------+---------+ 
| id | titre   | contenu |
+----+---------+---------+ 
| 1  | titre1  | lorem 1 |
| 4  | titre2  | lorem2  |
| 3  | titre3  | lorem3  |
+----+---------+---------+
```

in table Comment

```
+----+--------------+---------+-----------+
| id | actualite_id | email   | message   |
+----+--------------+---------+-----------+ 
| 1  |       1      | e@e.com | someText  |
| 2  |       4      | b@b.com | someText1 |
| 3  |       4      | a@a.com | text      |
| 4  |       3      | q@a.com | text2     |
+----+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

I tried to do this operation with the **Api-platform** method PUT it doesn't work :

Json request :
URL : http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/actualites/2

```
{
  "id": 4
}
```

nothing change !

Also i tried to craeact a costum controller to do this operation :

```
// scr/Controller/CustomController.php
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Actualite;
use App\Entity\Comment;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class CustomController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     *
     * @Route("/cid")
     */

    public function cidAction()
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $actualite = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Actualite::class)
            ->cid('2', '4');
        return new Response('ok', Response::HTTP_CREATED);

    }
}
```

and

```
<?php
/// src/RepositoryActualiteRepository.php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Actualite;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method Actualite|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Actualite|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Actualite[]    findAll()
 * @method Actualite[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class ActualiteRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Actualite::class);
    }
    /**
     * @return Actualite[] Returns an array of Actualite objects
     */
    public function cid($id, $value)
    {
      $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->update()
        ->set('a.id', $value)
        ->where('a.id = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $id); 

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

I get Error violation :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`api`.`comment`, CONSTRAINT `FK_9474526CA2843073` FOREIGN KEY (`actualite_id`) REFERENCES `actualite` (`id`))
```

How can i change the ID of a item in Actualite entity , and change the actualite_id in the related entity?

How can I do this operation ?

Comment: Can you share more of your entities' source code? (id property, and related getters and setters) Also, please separate code from different files in your answer so they do not appear in the same code block, as to avoid confusion.

Comment: Also you have not showed that you tried anything, or when/where it should happen. Is this a one time operation? Is it performed in response to an ajax request? Please elaborate on exactly what the problem is, thanks

Comment: thks, you can check the update : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260208/method-put-onetomany-relation-api-platform?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: i update the question up

Comment: Have you tried the method mentioned here https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/issues/129#issuecomment-66863968 ? I have found several references to changing the id generator, you will need to add a setter for the id.

Comment: doesn't work !! what i want is: – change the row id(Actualite) and the related row actualite_id(Comment) on update method not insert